# How do I take user input and use it to change a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program that takes user input and changes a variable with that input and create an iframe. For example, if the user input was https://google.com it would create an Iframe of Google. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <input id="url" type="text" placeholder="https://" /><button
            onclick="document.getElementById('input').value"
          >
          <script src=
          ./script.js></script>
</html>
```

That is the HTML, and here is the Javascript:

```js
var thing = (document.getElementById('input').value)
function iframe(){ var a,b,c;c="$thing", b=document.createElement("iframe"), b.setAttribute("src",c),b.setAttribute("id","rusic-modal"), b.setAttribute("style","position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: -2; left: -2; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 99999999999; background-color: #fff;"), a=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],a.appendChild(b)})).call(this)
```

I don't understand why its not working. I'm decently versed in javascript but I'm no master.

Comment: You're calling `getElementById('input')` even tho the `<input>`'s ID is `url`.

Comment: So I need to set both of them to url?

Comment: As @0stone0 points out, it should be `document.getElementById('url')` or `document.querySelector('input')`. Further, your template string should be using backticks instead of quotations, and curly braces around the variable: `\`${thing}\``

Comment: Actually, why even bother with template literals. Just use `c = thing`.

Comment: I'm now getting ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
    at /script.js:2:352``` and I'm not sure where it is

Comment: Why is this closed as duplicated for `string interpolation` ?? This has nothing to do with it!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `` for string with variable and also add `{}` after `$`
It should looks like this

```
c = `${thing}`
```

Tryout this

Comment: Where do I put that?

Edit: NVM I see it

Comment: after definition var a, b, c. You wright c = "$thing". Try to change, hope it helps you

Comment: @arze-dev Why you using commas instead of semicolons?